# Como utilizar a subtração do Excel em um conjunto de números?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Pretendo subtrair todos os valores dessa pequena tabela, mas caso eu tenha 100 valores diferentes, teria alguma fórmula para resumir todos os valores do mesmo jeito da formula soma, EX: =SOMA(B3:B8), sem precisar especificar célula por célula? Pois no excel não existe fórmula "=SUB()", no caso eu queria também que tivesse a divisão "=DIV", como eu procedo diante desse problema??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, vai subtrair o que do que?
Se for fazer algo equivalente a função Soma no final você teria um valor negativo: -360. Se esse for o objetivo pode fazer: **=SOMA(B3:B8) * -1**

Caso vc queira substituir todo o valor de um valor que esteja na celula C1 por exemplo pode fazer: **=C1 - SOMA(B3:B8).**

Para dividir você pode usar a Barra: '/', exemplo: **=4 / 2**

Comment: Sim, minha intenção é subtrair todos esse "valores R$" por completo. Eu usei essa sua formula `=SOMA(B3:B8)*` porém o resultado foi "360" sendo que quando eu subtrai na calculadora o resultado foi "340"

Comment: -340 porque na calculadora você está considerando o primeiro positivo e o restante negativo. Caso queira explique qual seu objetivo com essa subtração, talvez consiga te ajudar.

Comment: Eu já verifiquei aqui, pois sempre ele vai tirar algum valor especifico dependendo da posição das sequencias da células, eu fiquei meio confuso aqui, mas a intenção era subtrair os valores, porém tinha que haver um numero especifico final para subtrair, fui eu que me enrolei aqui kkkk